# Mock function is not identified as called, after a button click inside the <a> tag

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a local function that should be called on a button click and set the state of a Boolean variable inside it. I tried to add unit test to this module to identify whether the button is clicked and the function is called following the button click.

But my test is failing. I tried by mock the function inside the 'describe' method yet it didn't work.

SomeComponent.js

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        openImagesDialog: false,
    }
  }

  fuctionToBeCalled = (val) => {
      this.setState({ openImagesDialog: val })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <a onClick={() => this.fuctionToBeCalled(true)} className="img-container float">
        {child components....}
      </a>
    )
  }
}
```

SomeComponent.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import SomeComponent from '../SomeComponent';
import SomeAnotherComp from "../SomeAnotherComp";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

function setup() {
  const props = {
    openImagesDialog: false
  }
  let enzymeWrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent {...props} />)
  return {
    props,
    enzymeWrapper
  }
}

describe('components', () => {
  const { props, enzymeWrapper } = setup()

  it('should call fuctionToBeCalled(){}', () => {
    const SomeAnotherCompProps = enzymeWrapper.find(SomeAnotherComp).props()
    const fuctionToBeCalled = jest.fn(()=>true);


    enzymeWrapper.find('a').simulate('click')
    expect(fuctionToBeCalled).toBeCalled();
    //expect(SomeAnotherCompProps.dialogOpen).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

I'd like to know is there any other way to try this out.

Comment: `fuctionToBeCalled` is just mocked inside your test. It has no relation to the component being tested. You'll need to get the `SomeComponent` component instance and check `functionToBeCalled` on that. But you'd be better off checking the component's state instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `openImagesDialog` is not a prop but a state in the component.
Secondly, `fuctionToBeCalled` is a function defined on component instance and you need `spy` on it instead of just creating a mock function . In order to do that you use `spyOn` on component instance. You can also check the state after simulating click

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import SomeComponent from '../SomeComponent'
import SomeAnotherComp from "../SomeAnotherComp";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

function setup() {
  const props = {
    openImagesDialog: false
  }
  let enzymeWrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent {...props} />)
  return {
    props,
    enzymeWrapper,

  }
}

describe('components', () => {
  const { props, enzymeWrapper } = setup()

  it('should call fuctionToBeCalled(){}', () => {
    const SomeAnotherCompProps = enzymeWrapper.find(SomeAnotherComp).props()

    const instance = enzymeWrapper.instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'fuctionToBeCalled');
    enzymeWrapper.find('a').simulate('click')
    expect(instance.fuctionToBeCalled).toBeCalled();
    expect(enzymeWrapper.state('openImagesDialog')).toEqual(true);
  })
})
```

Comment: this solution solved my problem. I needed to check whether the state is changed after  the button click. That's why I kept is as a prop. But it seems there should be another way to trigger state changes :/

Comment: @HasiniSilva I added the code to check state update too

Comment: How did I miss these. I couldn't find these in jest official doc. Thanks for your solution. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)